# SQL SELECT query return total COUNT when filtering with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need a select query from two tables, `Car` and `CarImage`. There will be multiple images for each car. I want to return the total image count and the image name for just the first image (`DisplayOrder = 1`) for each car, but adding this where clause results in the image count always equal to one. How can I return the total image count and image name of just the first image for each car?

My simplified query looks like this:

```
SELECT c.Id,
        c.Make,
        c.Model,
        ci.ImageName,
        COUNT(ci.ImageName) AS ImageCount
FROM Car c
JOIN CarImage ci
ON c.Id = ci.CarId
WHERE ci.DisplayOrder = 1
GROUP BY (ci.ImageName) <-- usually need some kind of `GROUP BY` to get count
```

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: That query would fail, the `GROUP BY` is incomplete. Also, normally, you wouldn't `GROUP BY` and aggregate the same expression (`ImageName` in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit clunky, but you can get there with conditional aggregation. Because null will always be less than non-null.

```
 SELECT c.Id,
        c.Make,
        c.Model,
        max(case when ci.displayOrder = 1 then ci.ImageName end) as first_image_name,
        COUNT(ci.ImageName) AS ImageCount
   FROM Car c
   JOIN CarImage ci
     ON c.Id = ci.CarId
  GROUP
     BY c.Id,
        c.Make,
        c.Model
```

Answer (score 1):

For fun, here's yet another option using the `first_value()` windowing function:

```
select ID, Make, Model, ImageName, count(*) ImageCount 
from (
    SELECT c.Id,
        c.Make,
        c.Model,
        FIRST_VALUE(ci.ImageName) OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY DisplayOrder) ImageName
    FROM Car c
    INNER JOIN CarImage ci on ci.carid = c.id
) t
group by id, make, model, ImageName
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/aT5cS1ZE

The advantage here is it will still correctly take the first image based on `DisplayOrder`, *even if something causes the numbering to start somewhere other than 1*.

This is important, because there many apps using a similar ordering column that never actually show the value to the user, but instead allow for things like drag/drop reordering. And in that situation, it's common to just set new values on the needed records, rather than setting everything to start from one all over again. So if you have 30 items, and drag the last item up to the top, that could potentially only update one record (from 30 to -1), instead of 30.

It also seems like there should be a way to do this using a lateral join (`APPLY`), but I'm not seeing it right away without needing the `CarImage` table at both layers, which means it's unlikely to be very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You may use subquery for that:

```
SELECT c.Id,
        c.Make,
        c.Model,
        (
           SELECT ci.ImageName FROM CarImage ci
           WHERE c.Id = ci.CarId AND ci.DisplayOrder = 1
        ) AS ImageName,
        (
           SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CarImage cic
           WHERE c.Id = cic.CarId GROUP BY cic.CarId
        ) AS ImageCount
FROM Car c
```

Comment: This will work! But it's probably the slowest of the four options here :( I might also switch the ImageName subquery to take the top 1 sorted by DisplayOrder, for the case where the numbering has gone awry.

Comment: Okay, I partly take that back. One of the other options won't work at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can use subquery

```
SELECT Id, Make, Model, ImageName, ImageCount
FROM (
    SELECT c.Id,
            c.Make,
            c.Model,
            ci.ImageName,
            COUNT(ci.ImageName) AS ImageCount,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY ci.DisplayOrder) AS rn
    FROM Car c
    JOIN CarImage ci ON c.Id = ci.CarId
    GROUP BY c.Id, c.Make, c.Model, ci.ImageName
) d
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: This will not work. You can't use ci.displayorder in the row_number() function because it's not part of the group, and making it part of the group breaks the count(). Proof: https://dbfiddle.uk/J8HQxuFM But windowing functions are a good strategy! See my answer for how to do it.